# How should I use session cookies with OVMM Rest API and Ansible URI Module

Tags: virtual-machine, ansible, oracle-vm-server

I am able to use the Oracle Virtual Machine Manager (OVMM) REST API successfully with the Ansible URI module with the exception that I have to pass the username and password to EACH call instead of grabbing the session cookies from the first call and using them thereafter.
As I understand it the following should work, however I get a '401 Unauthorized' from the second call.
I have tried a number of variations in the second call. When I debug the playbook I see the cookies (JSESSIONID and _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_JSESSIONID) are being passed as expected.
To be clear, if I change the second API call to use basic_auth, username and password it works.

```
  - name: Get OVM Manager
    local_action:
        module: uri
        url: "{{ baseuri }}/Manager"
        url_username: "{{ ovmUser }}"
        url_password: "{{ ovmPassword }}"
        validate_certs: false
        force_basic_auth: true
        method: GET
    register: login

  - name: Get info about VMs
    local_action:
      module: uri
      url: "{{ baseuri }}/Vm/id"
      validate_certs: false
      method: GET
      headers:
        Cookie: "{{ login.cookies_string }}"  # Why doesn't this work???
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below parameter instead:

```
  headers:
    Cookie: "{{ login.set_cookie }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, but login.set_cookie, login.cookies_string and login.cookies all fail for me with a 401.